# How much damage is done to ascorbic acid vitamin C content by sunlight and fluorescent light?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I left a large clear bag of ascorbic acid exposed to fluorescent light and sunlight for 48 hours.  The sunlight was direct for several hours in the afternoon.  How much has the effectiveness of vitamin C been damaged?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ascorbic acid in solid crystallic form is much less sensitive to light and oxidation, compared to its solutions ( especially if in ascobate form ). Another lucky consequence is only the outer layer has been exposed to the light, the inner bag content is not disturbed.

It is hard to quantify the impact. Empirical evaluation could be if it changed the colour of the outer layer. But even if it did, the change of the overall acid content in the bag would be negligible.

Comment: I appreciate your responding to the question.  How much sunlight and/or fluorescent light would it take to degrade the vitamin C content of sealed bags of dry ascorbic acid powder?  What circumstances would be needed to reduce effectiveness of vitamin C by 5%?

Comment: Also, what is the ideal temperature for storing ascorbic acid powder?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Effectiveness would be the same, just amount would be 5% less. About 5% would have to be exposed to light, exposing it long enough.  For storage, room temperature, dark and dryness is enough.